# How to auto deploy Docker Image on own server with GitLab?

Tags: spring, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to Google it for few hours, but can't find it.
I have Java/Spring application (+MySQL if it matters) and I am looking to create CI for that.

**I know what to do and how:**

1. I know that I have to move my Git repo to Gitlab.
2. Push to repo will trigger CI script.
3. Gitlab will build my docker image into Gitlab Docker Registry.

**Question is:**

What do I have to do to force docker compose on my VPS to pull the new image from Gitlab and restart the server? 
I know (correct me if I am wrong) that on my VPS I should run `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up` inside my app folder, but I have literally no idea how to make it automatically with Gitlab?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> What do I have to do to force docker compose on my VPS to pull the new image from Gitlab and restart the server?

@m-uu, you don't need restart the server at all, just do `docker-compose up` to pull new image and restart service

> I know (correct me if I am wrong) that on my VPS I should run docker-compose pull && docker-compose up inside my app folder, but I have literally no idea how to make it automatically with Gitlab?

Yes, you are on the right way. Look at my Gitlab CI configuration file, I think it doesn't difficult to change it for Java project. Just give you ideas how to build, push to your registry and deploy an image to your server. One thing you need to do is generate SSH keys and push public to server (.ssh/authorized_keys) and private to GITLAB pipeline secret variable (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#secret-variables)

```
cache:
  key: "cache"
  paths:
  - junte-api

stages:
  - build
  - build_image
  - deploy

build:
  image: golang:1.7
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/key && chmod 600 ~/key
    - ssh-add ~/key
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

    - go get -u github.com/kardianos/govendor
    - mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/github.com/junte/junte-api
    - mv * $GOPATH/src/github.com/junte/junte-api
    - cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/junte/junte-api
    - govendor sync
    - go build -o junte-api
    - cd -
    - cp $GOPATH/src/github.com/junte/junte-api .

build_image:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build_image
  script:
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE

deploy-dev:
  stage: deploy
  image: junte/ssh-agent
  variables:
    # should be set up at Gitlab CI env vars
    SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: $SSH_DEV_PRIVATE_KEY
  script:
    # copy docker-compose yml to server
    - scp docker-compose.dev.yml root@SERVER_IP:/home/junte/junte-api/
    # login to gitlab registry       
    - ssh root@SERVER_IP docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
    # then we cd to folder with docker-compose, run docker-compose pull to update images, and run services with `docker-compose up -d`
    - ssh root@SERVER_IP "cd /home/junte/junte-api/ && docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml pull api-dev && HOME=/home/dev docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d"
  environment:
      name: dev
  only:
    - dev
```

You also need Gitlab runner with Docker support. How install it look at in Gitlab doc, please.

About stages:

- `build` - just change it to build what you need
- `build_image` - very simple, just login to gitlab registry, build new image and push it to registry. Look at `cache` part, it need to cache files between stages and can be different for you.
- `deploy-dev` - that part more about what you asked. Here first 6 commands just install ssh and create your private key file to have access to your VPS. Just copy it and add your SSH_PRIVATE_KEY to secret vars in Gitlab UI. Last 3 SSH commands more interesting for you.

Comment: 1. Where you configure SSH_PRIVATE_KEY, IP etc for your VPS?

Comment: @MU on gitlab <Project> - Settings - CI/CD Pipelines and Secret Variables part

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate more what is going on in the deploy script? I can try to understand parts, but would prefer to know what happens in each line.

Comment: @MU well, I've added more info to post and also commented most interesting lines in my configuration file. It should be enough to run your own setup. Don't hesitate read Gitlab docs for more info)))

Comment: So nice, thank you! Last thing (sorry!) - how to specify my container from GitLab in Docker Compose yml ? I have to use my container from GitLab + MySQL

Comment: FAIL:
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/key && chmod 600 ~/key
$ ssh-add ~/key
Enter passphrase for /root/key: ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: @MU generate ssh keys without password http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id

Comment: @MU in docker compose you should set image like -> image: registry.gitlab.com/<group>/<project>/image, you can see image path on gitlab.com -> "Registry" page of the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146775/discussion-between-m-u-and-vvelikodny).

Comment: not sure if you see that, but I started the chat with you