# How to automatically deploy and run docker images on server?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to setup the deployment of docker images to Linux server (Debian 10). 
I looked over the internet to find an easy solution to deploy images from docker repository onto a server automatically.
I know that Docker Hub has webhooks. 
Also, there is an option to use Kubernetes, but it seems to be a bit too much for a simple application running on one server. 
What I am looking for is a way for server to detect that docker image has been updated, so that it downloads it and runs the newest version.

Currently, I have setup automatic build of docker images on Azure DevOps that are pushed to private repository on Docker Hub (I will most likely move to privately hosted Nexus repository). 
I am looking for suggestions on how to do it with relatively low complexity (e.g. should I use docker-compose for it or some sort of bash script on a server).

The closest thing to what I am looking for is this solution: [How to auto deploy Docker Image on own server with GitLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545635/how-to-auto-deploy-docker-image-on-own-server-with-gitlab)
I would like to know if this is the recommended way to do or are there any other, possibly easier ways to approach it.

Comment: Is the process that builds the docker image under your control? If so then consider using a continuous deployment tool. If the process that builds docker image is not in your control then you could still use a continuous deployment tool to monitor deployed images using webhooks and deploy when a change is detected.

Comment: Yes I have control over building process. Current problem is that I cannot find an easy explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Considered using Jenkins to docker image and use the jenkins pipelines to deploy when a new image is built.

Comment: I'd like to know a little more about the deployment process. How are you deploying the image first time on the server, or what happens when a new server starts ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I currently have not started it on a server as I have not figured out a way to do it. I was thinking to start it using `docker run` or `docker-compose up` for the first time and then have some way to automatically pull new image, stop the old one and run new version. I want to run it on one server. I am not planning to add more for now if this is what you are asking.

Comment: When you try to deploy, if you stop the service and then restart it with new image, there will a short span in which no requests will be served. It will be kind of a downtime. Is it okay to have this short downtime ?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande I think for now it will be ok.

Comment: Cool. Basically what you are trying to achieve here is continuous deployment. I would prefer this way (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44545635/how-to-auto-deploy-docker-image-on-own-server-with-gitlab) this is like creating a pipeline for deployment. You can also add a stage to run unit tests if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this project that looks good as a solution for my case.

https://containrrr.github.io/watchtower/