# Docker network not found with gitlab ci.yml on docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

I'm trying to make a ci cd with docker and gitlab pipeline.

i'm using nginx proxy manager on a docker, and add git lab runner on my vps. I think i miss something in the config.

Because when I'm doing a `docker network ls` with `gitlab-ci.yml` the nginx proxy manager network is missing:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
86c186c7d935        bridge              bridge              local
9c1df435a8a6        host                host                local
ade22cc32026        none                null                local
```

But as root on my vps terminal is right here:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                        DRIVER    SCOPE
fec1b6465ccd   bridge                      bridge    local
d2f1618cf9a9   host                        host      local
b879f034d44a   nginxproxymanager_default   bridge    local
54cfc9978bc1   none                        null      local
```

of course with this I have an error with the `docker-compose.yml` when gitlab-ci try to run docker-compose up -d

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Network nginxproxymanager_default declared as external, but could not be found. Please create the network manually using `docker network create nginxproxymanager_default` and try again.
```

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image:
    name: docker/compose:latest

services:
    - docker:dind

before_script:
  - docker info
  - docker-compose --version

stages: 
    - deploy
        
deployement:
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - main
    script:
        - docker network ls
        - docker build -t do-tout .
        - docker-compose down
        - docker-compose up -d
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:
  client:
    image: do-tout
    container_name: do-tout
    networks:
      - nginxproxymanager_default
networks:
  nginxproxymanager_default:
    external: true
```

Anyone can help me with this ?

Bonus: I dont know how to manage environnement variables to replace .env any good tutorials ?

Comment: Since you declare the network as `external: true`, Compose won't create it; it expects it to already exist.  For most common cases you don't need to declare `networks:` at all since Compose provides its own network named `default` that gets used automatically.  Can you delete all of the `networks:` blocks in the file?

Comment: Hey thx for your answer @DavidMaze, yes i can but to make nginx proxy manager working i have to add the container to the nginx proxy manager network. With docker cmd line :

`docker run --network nginxproxymanager_default --name=containername imagename `

but seams to not working :/

Comment: You need to manually create it, then, since it's declared as external.

Comment: @DavidMaze

Thx it work without networks
I thought I had to put a network to link it with nginxproxymanager

Comment: actually it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Your install in gitlab isn't running in the context of your VPS, it's running within DinD:

```
services:
    - docker:dind
```

You need to either point your deployment to the docker engine in your VPS, or to test in DinD, you need to first create the network:

```
deployement:
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - main
    script:
        - docker network create nginxproxymanager_default
        - docker network ls
        - docker build -t do-tout .
        - docker-compose down
        - docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Hello,
I have some questions.
I tried with 
```
deployement:
    stage: deploy
    only:
        - main
    script:
        - docker network create nginxproxymanager_default
        - docker network ls
        - docker build -t do-tout .
        - docker-compose down
        - docker-compose up -d
```
command work but container is not link with the nginxproxymanager_default

Can i run directly on my server the gitlab ci ? to have access to the nginxproxymanager_default ?

Comment: @Macsim you probably want to look at how you deploy to an environment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/

Comment: If the runner is on the docker host, you may be able to share the docker socket with the tasks performed on that runner, but realize the security risk you have with anyone able to run a job on that runner having root on the host. Also see this question that talks about ssh access: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44545635/596285

Answer (score 0):

I found this part of the documentation very helpful:
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#network-configurations

If you need to access persistent services from Gitlab-CI, through a project-specific Gitlab Runner, then all you need to do is create a persistent docker network on the host (where the Gitlab Runner runs):

```bash
docker network create test
```

Add this network to the Runner's `config.toml` with the line `network_mode="test"`, e.g.:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "Gitlab-CI Test runner"
  url = "..."
  token = "..."
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
    network_mode="test"
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

The Runner should reload the changed configuration automatically (every 3 seconds).

**Now your CI jobs have access to `test` docker network of the Gitlab Runner. Start a service with name `testdb` and you can access this service's IP via DNS (`testdb`) in Gitlab-CI Jobs.**